# Math Calculations on the Pandas.dateColumn vs Pandas.dateColumn.values

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

When working with columns of `datetime` in pandas, does it matter whether we divide the columns directly by an integer vs. dividing the values of the columns with the integer?

```
df['mid_date'] = df['start_date'] + (df['end_date'] - df['start_date']) /2
```

compared to

```
df['mid_date'] = df['start_date'] + (df['end_date'] - df['start_date']).values /2
```

Both seems to give the same result during my tests, wondering which is the best practice?

Comment: The key difference here is that `values` attribute returns a np array, this can be useful when you want to assign the values and ignore the index which the former will generate and will mean that the lhs will try to align on the index, in your case it makes no difference as you're adding the result to `df['start_date']` which will have an index anyway

Answer (score 0):

In your case there is no difference, generally calling `values` attribute returns a np array of your data, typical cases where this is necessary is when you want the array as plain values without the index/column names as pandas will attempt to align on index and column values.

In your case you're assigning to `df['start_time']` so the result will still be a pandas series which will have an index.

Sometimes some apis don't like pandas df/series as params and you have to call `values` to make them happy but this only happens for some apis, I historically encountered this with sk-learn but I don't know if recently all these bugs have been squashed or not with some of the corner cases.